# Ionic 2 Google Maps Native Map Type

Tags: google-maps, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ngcordova

How do I set the `mapType` using Ionic 2 and google maps native

```
import {
 GoogleMaps,
 GoogleMap,
 GoogleMapsEvent,
 GoogleMapOptions,
 CameraPosition,
 MarkerOptions,
 Marker
} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';



constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public googleMaps: GoogleMaps) { }


    let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
      camera: {
        target: {
          lat: 43.0741904,
          lng: -89.3809802
        },
        zoom: 18,
        tilt: 30
      },
      'mapType': this.googleMaps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
```

Error:`Property 'MapTypeId' does not exist on type 'GoogleMaps'.`

[From the documentation](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/blob/master/v1.4.0/class/Map/README.md#change-the-map-type) it states `map.setMapTypeId(plugin.google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID);` But I can't figure out what type `plugin` is?

Comment: Try mapType: "MAP_TYPE_ROADMAP" instead

Comment: That worked! @anatoly.sukhanov Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

To use MapType in typescript you need to define a variable of type MapType, and then use it in Google maps options like this:

```
import { GoogleMapOptions, MapType } from '@ionic-native/google-maps';

let myMapType: MapType = 'MAP_TYPE_CONSTANT_VALUE';
 let config: GoogleMapOptions = {
   mapType: myMapType
 }
```